# How to add active class in this loop in which is dynamically showing the menus Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vue.js, laravel-8

How to add active class in this loop in which is dynamically showing the menus Vue Js?
I couldn't place active class for the open menus.

```
 <a v-bind:href="module.route" class="nav-link">
     //module.route is a database column
      <i :class="module.icon" ></i>
        //module.icons is a database column
       <p>
         {{ module.name }}
            //module.name is a database column
       </p>
  </a>
```

Its showing the list of menus from database .Now I just want to make the open menu active.

Comment: How is ths related to PHP, Laravel or MySQL (other than the data initially comes from the db?) Please give us some more context.

Comment: is module a prop (are you passing it)? or a data? If `module.icon` is a string it should add it as class with your given code

Comment: Where's the menu in there? what should be dynamic? What's the expected/desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way.

```html
<!-- App.vue HTML PART -->
<li v-for = "(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index" class="nav-link" @click="active_tab = tab" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : tab === active_tab }">
    ...
</li>
```

I added all the tabs I wanted to add in an array named `tabs`

```js
<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  data() {
    return {
      active_tab: "Tab1",
      tabs: ["Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"]
    }
}

</script>
```

> v-for = "(tab, index) in tabs"

This is going to create one `<li>` for every `tab` in the array `tabs`

> class="nav-link" @click="active_tab = tab" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : tab === active_tab }"

All the items are going to have a class of `nav-link` and on top of that with `v-bind`, it's going to add `active` to the element's classlist if the variable `active_tab` is equal to `tab`. And everytime the user clicks on one of the tabs, with `@click` it'll change `active_tab` to the `tab` that the user clicked.

Styling

```css
.nav-link {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    /* how the element should look when it is normal */
}
.nav-link.active {
    background-color: var(--hover-color);
    /* when it is active */
}
```